# How to vertically center align a JScrollPane in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel with a GridLayout consisting of 1 row and 2 Columns.

Inside the first column, I have a JPanel consisting of a Jpanel and a Jtree.
Inside the second column, I have a JScrollPane consisting of a JTable.

How can I center-align the JscrollPAne to appear vertically center-aligned? currently, It is showing at the top and not at the center.

Here is an image:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Layout manager to save you :) Inside the second column, use a panel with `GridBagLayout` , and insert the JScrollPane into the panel, you can specify the position of components in panel using GridBagConstraints.

See this for more information : [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 2):

You for your `JScrollPane` in the 2nd column, you will need to wrap it with a `JPanel`. Then you will need to set a layout manager for the new `JPanel`. I would probably use `GridBagLayout` as it gives you more precise control and you can achieve the vertical centering you desire with it.

You will have to add a fake `JPanel` into the wrapper `JPanel` to fill in the whitespace you are looking for.

So in short you will have:
`JPanel` with `GridLayout` (1 row, 2 columns)

Column 1:

- `JTree`

Column 2:

- `JPanel` with `GridBagLayout` which then holds:

  - `JPanel`with `GridBagConstraints` (for whitspace)
  - `JScrollPane` with `GridBagConstraints`

You might need to add another `JPanel` below the `JScrollPane` if you want whitespace down there too. I'm not 100% sure what your looking for. With the `GridBagConstraints` you can precisely control the layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have chosen Sanjay's answer because it was posted first :)